# spark streaming application - deployment best practices

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using `spark-submit cluster mode` deployment for my application to run it in production.

But this places a requirement of having the jars in the same path in all the nodes and also the config file which is passed as argument in the same path.
  I am running spark in standalone mode and I don't have hadoop or S3 environment. This mode of deployment is inconvenient.
  I could do spark submit from one node in client mode but it doesn't provide high availablity .

What is the best way to deploy spark streaming applications in production ?

Comment: Hi @Knight71 

If you can share some thoughts on this then it would be really great.

Comment: We were using spark job server for deloyment. It took care of distributing jar. Now we have moved to spark on kubernetes a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for responding back. We are also at same place. Thinking to use JAR repository so that every node can make use of it. Any thing you want to add here?

Comment: Not much. SJS was working good.